# SASS url() direct path

Tags: css, svg, sass

I use sass in my project. And have a problem:
The scss file is one lvl lower in directory that resulting css file. Because of that my compiler compile `url(#CSSLocator)` as `url(../#CSSLocator)`. I need to use that `url` function as location to filter (svg filter in this same file).

Do you know how to tell SASS compiler to treat this path directly as it is, not change it?

**EDIT**:

My directory structure is

> content/main.scss
>
> content/styles/main.css

and `filter: url('#GradientMap');` after compiling generate `url("../#GradientMap");`, probably because of the dir structure.

Comment: Can you show your project directory structure and the how the code that's causing the error is written in your `scss` file?

Comment: what versions of sass and compass are you using?

Comment: To be honest I have completly no idea. I'm using [this visual studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c) to compile that. But I did it as below, just hardcoded inline style. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just run `sass -v` in terminal and `compass -v`. I was doing some research and I think it may be because of the version that's why. If it is you won't have to hard code it

Comment: But I'm doing it on windows, and do not have `sass` and `compass` installed localy. It is bundled with this extension, so I can't check it that way.

Comment: Oh I see. Anyway you can take a look at these links [github sass issue #989](https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/989) and [github compass issue #412](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/412). Think you're facing the same issue and it seems it's a bug in certain versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't figured it out how to do this. I just hardcoded inline style in my html insted of fighting with Sass.

```
<img src="urlToPic" style="filter: url('#GradientMap');">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same direct path of the css file, Sass is just a compiler of css.

Comment: I know, but in my project CSS is one lvl deeper in drectory means:
/file.scss
/content/file.css so Sass add ../ at the beginning which (in this case) I don't want and I'm looking for a way to make sass compile this one directly.